# How to put in verbatim text with the tikz graphdrawing library?

Tags: tikz-pgf, verbatim, tikz-graphdrawing

I want to draw a graph with the tikz graph drawing functionality.  And I want some text in some nodes to use a monospace font.  I tried this.  I compiled with `lualatex`.  I got the error `\verb illegal in command argument.`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {graphs,graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary {layered}
\begin{document}
\tikz \graph [layered layout] {
  text/{\verb|text|}
};
\end{document}
```

Without `verb||` it compiles fine.  Also `text[as="\verb|text|"]` gives the same error.

How to put in verbatim text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want monospace font, try `\texttt{text}` instead of `\verb|text|`.